# Create Node and related Node at the same time?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have a content-type (Recipe) that is created by anonymous users and can be rated/reviewed with another content-type (Review).

Users should be able to write a Recipe and a Review related to that Recipe at the same time on the same Page. I think I'm searching for the wrong things but I can't find a solution for this Problem without the need to write a new module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module will get you that functionality (assuming your reference field is provided by the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/Entityreference) module).

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
>
> The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>
> Existing entities can also be referenced.

Comment: One little follow up question: Is it possible that other users can add a review after the initial node (Recipe/Review) is created?

Comment: Definitely, but that'll take a bit more work. Short version, enable comments on the node type and install the Fivestar module. With a bit of configuration you can get a good review system going without any code

Comment: Thanks for the reply Clive, but i think i didn't i didn't make clear what my question was =/. So I will try again and then stop bothering you.
I meant can another User add another Review (The Content-Type) to the Recipe. So that I can have one Recipe with x Reviews(Content Type) and the initial review was created during the Recipe creation.

Comment: Oh I get ya :) That would be more down to permissions, but yes, if those are set up right then any user will be able to edit the parent node and new child node(s). If you need that to be limited to one per user, or something, then things get more difficult

Answer (score 0):

See also [references_dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog):

> This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference
>   fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through
>   a dialog.